# Removing repeated rows with each interval from data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help to remove all repeated rows in the same interval values of data.frame.

For example, i have a data.frame like :

```
Time                X   Y   Z
01/01/2011 00:00    101 200 302
01/01/2011 00:05    101 200 302
01/01/2011 00:10    101 200 302
01/01/2011 00:20    100 200 303
01/01/2011 00:25    100 200 303
01/01/2011 00:30    100 200 303
01/01/2011 00:35    101 200 302
01/01/2011 00:40    100 200 303
01/01/2011 00:45    100 200 303
```

And after removing the repeated row values (x,y,z), i will have a result just like below :

```
Time                X   Y   Z
01/01/2011 00:00    101 200 302
01/01/2011 00:20    100 200 303
01/01/2011 00:35    101 200 302
01/01/2011 00:40    100 200 303
```

What i have tried with : unique or duplicate function, but they give the different result.

ex/ `eliminate <- data[!duplicated(data[,c("X","Y","Z")]),]`

This code just delete all the duplicated values in the all data.frame.

Is there somebody can help me for find the solution?

Thanks before, Regards,

Yougyz

Comment: `dups = df[duplicated(df[,2:4]),]` and
`nodups = df[!(duplicated(df[,2:4])),]` worked for me. Could you show us what you get when you use the `duplicated()` function?

Comment: That only gets the unique items.  The desire is not for that but for the first item in a run of duplicated items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code makes your three columns of interest a single vector.  Then, I just test for equality between the vector and it's offset by 1.  When that is false you've had a transition to a new XYZ item.

```
n <- nrow(ss)
xyz <- with(ss, paste0(X, Y, Z))
sel <- xyz[1:(n-1)] !=  xyz[2:n]
ss[c(TRUE,sel),] #the first one would always be true
```

This is about 3x faster than Julius answer.  The advantage should become greater as the dataset grows.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant way:

```
data  <- within(data, C <- paste(X, Y, Z, sep = ""))
rl <- rle(data$C)$lengths
data <- data[c(1, cumsum(rl)[-length(rl)] + 1), 1:(ncol(data)-1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @Julius for your help, its works and give us expected results.. Well, i dont know how is the mos elegant way.. But, this is already good.. ;)